# How is 76 frames calculated mfcc for 1 sec signal with 25 msec window and 10 msec overlap?

Tags: spectrogram, mfcc

I was studying about keyword detection and while doing some reading, I read we take 1 sec audio signal.

We then divide it into 25msec sub sections with and overlap of 10msec. We apply mel filter bank and have 26 filter outputs. Now we color code them to create spectrogram. The number of rows in spectrogram are 26 and the number of columns is 76.

How does this 76 come?
If we take 25msec window with 10ms overlap then we get frames as

0-25
15-40
30-55
...

This comes to only 66 frames. How does 76 comes?

This is mentioned in many literatures.

I am confused how come 76 is present.

Another question is from the screenshot below. They use 64 bin mfcc. I read mel filter can be between 20-40. How come they get 64?

[image]

Comment: Link to image : https://imgur.com/a/2A7VDXh

Comment: Text says "10ms shift" not "10ms overlap". That still doesn't make 76 though.

Comment: @Hilmar yes 10ms shift will make around 98 frames. Is that correct?